# Drupal 7 cutom form in custom template

Tags: drupal

I`m new to drupal 7 module development. what I want to do is to create a Search page in which I have the form on top of the page and after submitting the form, will get the result on same page below the form.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Broad question, but try using views module (https://www.drupal.org/project/views) with exposed filters for search form. It requires no programming skills - you can do all from back-end. Possibilities are limited eventually, but for some basic search form would do the job.